# Modular multiplication of large numbers

Tags: c, math, multiplication, modular-arithmetic

I need to find an efficient algorithm for doing modular multiplication of three numbers.

In other words is there a way to find this in C?

```
(100100101010001001 * 1010000100100010 * 10010001001010100101001) % 1000000007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to avoid integer overflow, you can transform

```
(a * b * c) % d
```

into

```
((((a % d) * (b % d)) % d) * (c % d)) % d
```

In C:

```
unsigned long work(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c, unsigned long d)
{
    unsigned long r = a % d;
    r *= b % d;
    r %= d;
    r *= c % d;
    r %= d;
    return r;
}
```

It can still overflow though, but less often than the naïve version. If you want to be positively sure it will not overflow then you should use some form of big numbers library like [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/). The usage would look like:

```
unsigned long work(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c, unsigned long d)
{
    mpz_t tmp, res;
    unsigned long r;
    mpz_init_set_ui(tmp, a);
    mpz_mul_ui(res, tmp, b);
    mpz_mul_ui(tmp, res, c);
    mpz_mod_ui(res, tmp, d);
    r = mpz_get_ui(res);
    mpz_clear(res);
    mpz_clear(tmp);
    return r;
}
```

Maybe Gmplib supports directly setting the result into the same variable as one of the operand but I am not sure. You would have to check this in the documentation.

Comment: well it certainly does overflow for the said example. Can we use libgmp in C??

Comment: @user1537727 Sure, Gmplib *is* C based. Edited to give an example.

Comment: @user1537727 Are the numbers you mention the maximum? Specifically is `1000000007` guaranteed to fit in 32 bits? What is your compiler? The edited solution should work on 64 bits platforms for your numbers.

Comment: @user1537727 Sorry, I had not noticed that one of the numbers, `10010001001010100101001`, is more than 64 bits. In this case you do not really have a choice but use some big numbers library.

Comment: > "In this case you do not really have a choice but use some big numbers library"

Wait wait, that's not true!
If you're starting with a big numeral
as a string, you can get its value
modulo the modulus as follows:
    uint64_t number = 0;
    for each digit in the numeral:
    {
        number *= 10;
        number += digit-'0';
        number %= modulus;
    }
Then proceed from there, no bigints needed.

Comment: woops, scratch the "number %= modulus" from that